# Using imports in an extended class?

Tags: php

I need to override a method in another class, so I extend it:

```
class Foo extends Bar
```

In class Bar there are some use statements:

```
use App\Whatever\ExampleClass
```

But when I try and call `ExampleClass` it's not found and I have to import it again in my extended class.

How can I use imported classes in the original class in my extended class?

Comment: could you save the class on a property of the object you are extending ?

Comment: How do `Foo` and `Bar` relate to `ExampleClass`?

Comment: You cannot "import" something into a class. The `use` statement imports things into a _file_.

Comment: Are you using an autoloader? http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ I am and i've never had this problem. Also you could use traits instead of extending the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use` merely establishes an *alias* (an alternative, presumably shorter, name) in the current file. Nothing more, nothing less. That alias doesn't persist across files, and is not bound to classes. It doesn't even "import" anything, it literally only allows you to refer to something by a more wieldy name.

Comment: Thanks, so I'll have to redo the alias in the extended class?

Comment: If you want to refer to `App\Whatever\ExampleClass` by a name other than its full name, yes.